# asp.net C# gridview pagination disable other buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have in my page some buttons and a gridview, I am using default gridview pagination by using only AllowPaging="true", the problem is when I go to page 2 inside the gridview all the button in the page become disabled and unclickable and I need to refresh the page to fix the issue,

any help will be appreciated.

here is one of my buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="search" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />
```

Comment: You didn't post any of the relevant code. Here's some information on how to use the `GridView`'s `AllowPaging` property ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using linkbutton instead of Button

Answer (score 0):

AllowPaging=true , are you using pageIndexChange methods? Do you have that coded? If so can you share your code we may be able to help you better.